# Flutter: Error "The 'Pods-Runner' target has frameworks with conflicting names: appinvokesdk.xcframework"

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, paytm

I have a problem with pod install.

With error

`[!] The 'Pods-Runner' target has frameworks with conflicting names: **appinvokesdk.xcframework**`

I am using Paytm payment gateway
(Paytm All-in-One SDK version 1.1.7),
Dart SDK version 2.18.2,
Flutter SDK version 3.0.5

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have old data in your Podfile that's why you are getting the error. You can deintegrate the pod first

```
pod deintegrate
```

You have to install the pods later

```
pod install
```

And also you should run this command after and before that process :

```
flutter clean
```